# Check if URL in a string and return an HTML link to it

Tags: c#, html, hyperlink

Okay so I'm struggling a bit here, I have a function that gets Facebook RSS feeds, however I want the string that it returns to contain `<a href = "">Link</a>` where there are any URLs.

Any ideas of how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this Regex expression to find a url, and make it a HTML link:

```
yourString = Regex.Replace(yourString,
                @"((http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)","<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
```

This will replace every link with `<a href = "the_link">the_link</a>`

For example, if yourString contains this:

```
Hello, this is some text. Please visit my website at http://www.google.com
```

Then yourString will contain this, after the Regex.Replace:

```
Hello, this is some text. Please visit my website at <a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>
```

Comment: Thanks but where is the "the_link"?

Comment: I don't understand your question. It will search in the string for URL's and will replace the URL into a HTML link.
I'll add an example

Comment: The variable 'the_link' is the string with the link in. If you dont have it you should be able to easily extract it by first finding a start of http:// https:// or www. and then the link ends where there is a space.